# Ruby Get Caller Object's Name Inside Method Using Default Library

Tags: ruby, object, methods

I have the following problem. I would like to have a method, let's call it method_A that check the object name that call method_A.

This is a simple reference, but what I'd be doing would be much more complicated than this, I understand that there's an alternative that can solve what I need in a much better way, but alas the code almost done, and I don't have enough time to tweak around much. Anyway, here it goes:

```
class Picture
  attr_accessor :size

  def resize
    name = self.get_object_name_here
    case name
    when Big #Can be string or variable, I don't mind
      self.size *= .5
    when Medium
    when Small
      self.size *= 2
    else
    end

  def get_object_name_here
    object_name
  end
end

Big = Picture.new
Medium = Picture.new
Small = Picture.new
Big.size = 10
Medium.size = 10
Small.size = 10
Big.resize       => 5
Medium.resize    => 10
Small.resize     => 20
```

If there's a way to just do

```
name = object_name
```

That would be very HELPFUL

Greatly Appreciated!

Edit: Sorry for the capitalized Big, Medium, Small. They are typos.

Comment: What do you mean by `object_name`? In your example would they be `Big, Medium and Small`?

Comment: Yes, yes, they would be Big, Medium, and Small.

Comment: I don't think it is possible what you want to achieve since those are the names of the variables which have been assigned to the `Picture` objects: it is impossible for the `Picture` know which variable you are using.

Comment: Well, any way to identify which object (not class) is calling this method would be very helpful. I just need the case operator to work.

Comment: Then you will have to change the class to add a setter for the name attribute, as you did for size.

Comment: Yea, I thought of that too, but what should I do so that each object would have different attribute automatically as they are initialized without having me to assign the attribute value of each object manually?

Comment: I'll add an answer for that, hang on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to change the definition of your class

```
class Picture
  attr_accessor :size, :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @size = 10
  end

  def resize
    case name
    when "Big"
      self.size *= 0.5
    when "Medium"
    when "Small"
      self.size *= 2
    else
    end
  end
end
```

The `initialize` method will be called by Ruby when you use `new` passing along all the arguments. You can use this class like this:

```
big = Picture.new("Big")
medium = Picture.new("Medium")
small = Picture.new("Small")

puts "before resize"

puts big.size
puts medium.size
puts small.size

big.resize
medium.resize
small.resize

puts "after resize"

puts big.size
puts medium.size
puts small.size
```

results in

```
before resize
10
10
10
after resize
5.0
10
20
```